Не получается внедрить javascript brige WebView в Android studio
Суть проблемы, нужно внедрить код

mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView); PPSJsBridge.init(new
JsbConfig.Builder()
// Indicates whether to accept the user agreement. The options are true (yes) and false (no).
.enableUserInfo(true)
.enableLog(true)
.build()); // Bind WebView to the JavaScript Bridge. bridge = new PPSJsBridge(mWebview);

в Activity.java проекта, согласно документации
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMSCore-Guides/publisher-service-js-integrating-sdk-0000001133475862
Все необходимые ресурсы подключил, при попытке внедрения кода
выделяет красным строки bridge = new PPSJsBridge(mWebview); и mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);  я не понимаю как заявить переменные чтобы их приняло.
Сам веб код который исполняется в проекте расположен в папке assets/www/index.html
Подскажете пожалуйста как запустить код корректно ?
